# Runpath Search Paths can't find library even with @rpath/library.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, dynamic-linking

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for hours.  I've been playing around with CMUSphinx's pocketsphinx library, running on OSX 10.10/XCode 7.2,and want to get my .app bundle to work on computers besides my own.  Most importantly, there are three dynamic libraries that have to be embedded in the .app bundle(`libpocketsphinx.3.dylib`, `libsphinxad.3.dylib`, and `libsphinxbase.3.dylib`), and then loaded using `Runpath Search Paths` settings in XCode.

I've read just about everything I can find on how to get this to work.  I should note that the .app bundle compiles/runs as intended on my own machine.  I've made sure that the libraries are copied into the .app bundle's `/Contents/Frameworks` folder.  The libraries are not using references, but are copied into my source folder (as per a forum post on this exact issue on CMUSphinx's page).  I've tried just about every combination of using `install_name_tool` for `@rpath/libraryname.dylib`, as well as `@loader_path` and `@executable_path` in both the executable (so changing it in XCode to @whatever_path/../Frameworks), as well as the three library files.  I also have tried `@loader_path/Frameworks` per another post here, but no luck.

Whats weird is the error I'm getting seems like it is loading `libsphinxad.3.dylib`, as both `libsphinxad.3.dylib` and `libsphinxad.3.dylib` rely on `libsphinxbase.3.dylib`, but I get this error in the crash report:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/SunGate/VoiceCommander.app/Contents/Frameworks/libsphinxad.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Note, the `/Volumes/SunGate/` is just a drive on another machine I'm testing this on.

I would *really* appreciate help with this!  I will do my best to provide any other information that might help solve this!

Answer (score 0):

I found this lib by using the "find" command on my system. Not surprisingly it was here

> sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/.libs/libsphinxbase.3.dylib

I linked it to /usr/local/lib/

> ln -s sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/.libs/libsphinxbase.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.3.dylib

And all set to go!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?